# How to write a script correctly in SHELL?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, exec

I execute the command as a user:

```
 admin@host:~#exec setsid -c /usr/bin/clish -x /usr/local/xml/
```

Then everything works as it should, but I need to make the script run right after the login utility for a specific user.

To do this, I specified the script I need in /etc/passwd/

```
admin:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/:/usr/sbin/admin_run
```

admin_run:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 exec setsid -c /usr/bin/clish -x /usr/local/xml
```

But everything works crookedly, signals are not intercepted, and in addition there is an error:

-sh: can't set tty process group: Inappropriate ioctl for device

How do I fix this?

Comment: You're running a non-interactive shell as the login shell.

Comment: You shouldn't have a space in `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: This is a typo when copying

Comment: How  I can  run  script interactively?

Comment: Try using the `-i` option to `/bin/sh`